# harmon.ie plugin greyed out in Outlook since build 1808

Tags: plugins, outlook, outlook-addin, harmon.ie

The issue appears in build 1808 of Outlook and with version 5.5.0.422 of the harmon.ie plugin. The "Optimize for compatibility" option provided as a solution in a separate question works here, but that's not a real option as it would be an instruction for all our users. Is there a Group Policy or harmon.ie update option?

Comment: You can deploy this registry key to users via GPO (aka Group Policy) like any registry key. You sys admin can define such GPO. We have also updated our web site with new harmon.ie free version that already encloses this registry key (just need to install new version)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is the new registry key also included in the new enterprise edition version?

Comment: Yes, the key is already enclosed in new Enterprise edition. By the way, if you are customer you should report issues to support@harmon.ie